# Making custom bullets click-able in a CSS unordered list

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-lists

So I used CSS to replace the bullets on a webpage with pictures of palm trees, change the fonts, move some items around, etc. The issue I have now is that only clicking the words will activate the link. Ideally I would like clicking the palm tree (the bullet) to have the same effect. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this approach when i was looking a while ago. http://simplebits.com/notebook/2004/07/18/clickable/ started following the blog as a result of it ;)

Comment: Good thought, but keep in mind that the article was written in 2004, and later flavors of HTML in modern browsers would treat the anchor tag as an inline element that doesn't take padding unless you set its display to inline-block.